# Xpath how to get all text in the tag

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, web-scraping

I have this html code:

```
<div id="m0" style="visibility:visible; display:block;">
 <table class="fl">
  <tr bgcolor="white"><td class="v px3"></td>
   <td class="ch">
     <a title="Id: NetViet" class="A3">NetViet</a></td>
   </tr>

<div id="m1" style="visibility:visible; display:block;">
 <table class="fl">
  <td class="ch">
   <A class="A3" title="Id: Kino Polska Muzyka" HREF="http://www.kinopolskamuzyka.pl/" TARGET="_blank">Kino Polska Muzyka</A>
 </tr>
  <td class="ch">
   <i>HBO3 HD</i></td>
 </tr>
  <td class="ch"> Faktura</td>
 </tr>
```

My xpath is : `tree.xpath('//div[@id="%s"]/table[@class= "fl"]/tr/td[@class="ch"]/a/text()'%div)`

but it does not give me all the channels. I want to get all text in `<td class="ch">`, the result that i want is:

```
[['NetViet'],['Kino Polska Muzyka','HB03','Faktura']]
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Besides your messed up html structure, remove 'tr' and 'a' nodes from your xpath, because not every 'td' is surrounded by those.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use css selectors to target td tag elements with that class? For this type of selection is it likely faster than xpath.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<div id="m0" style="visibility:visible; display:block;">
 <table class="fl">
  <tr bgcolor="white"><td class="v px3"></td>
   <td class="ch">
     <a title="Id: NetViet" class="A3">NetViet</a></td>
   </tr>

<div id="m1" style="visibility:visible; display:block;">
 <table class="fl">
  <td class="ch">
   <A class="A3" title="Id: Kino Polska Muzyka" HREF="http://www.kinopolskamuzyka.pl/" TARGET="_blank">Kino Polska Muzyka</A>
 </tr>
  <td class="ch">
   <i>HBO3 HD</i></td>
 </tr>
  <td class="ch"> Faktura</td>
 </tr>
 '''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
items = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('td.ch')]
print(items)
```